# How can I produce a file?

Tags: python

I have a text file example.txt which represents the

```
def a 

 return a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Hint: this can be achieved with using `str.split('|')` and simple dict value assignments like `dict[key] = value`

Comment: `{author:title for author,title in map(str.strip, line.split("|")) for line in f}`

Comment: or in fact `dict(map(str.strip, line.split("|") for line in f)`

Comment: I don't know specifically how to assign the values after '|' or the keys

Comment: You have got good answers in the form of comments. My suggestion is to improve your knowledge of python's basic data types and operators.

Comment: thank you very much now its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers in the comments are more pythonic, but if you want a more easily understandable example

```
>>> books = {}
>>> line = "Calculus | James Stewart"
>>> parts = line.split('|') # can also do title, author = line.split('|')
>>> books[parts[0].strip()] = parts[1].strip()
>>> print(books)
{'Calculus': 'James Stewart'}
```

Comment: thanks now i got the idea of it :D